# Replacing sukkah walls one at a time after schach is already on the succah

Tags: halacha, sukkah

*Remah* Shulchan Aruch OC [at end of 635:1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.635.1?lang=bi) - רמ"א בשולחן ערוך אורח חיים בסוף סימן תרלה:

**ואין לעשות הסכך קודם שיעשה הדפנות**:

**The *schach* should not be made (put up on the Sukkah) before making (constructing) the walls.**

Question: A sukkah needs a minimum of 3 walls. If 4 walls were constructed, and schach was put on top of them, and then one removed each one of the 4 walls, one wall at a time and immediately replaced it with another wall, without removing any schach, until all 4 walls had been replaced, after the schach was already  on the sukkah, would the Succah remain kosher?

Would we say that since all the present walls of the succah were constructed after the schach, the sukkah is not kosher, or do we say that since only one wall was removed and a time, and immediately replaced by another, so the sukkah always had the minimal 3 walls and remained kosher at all times, and thus is still kosher?

Comment: The underlying issue is תעשה ולא מן העשוי. Maybe that could open some approaches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The Mishna Brurah on that comment of the Remah](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.635.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) explains that the issue is that at the time the schach is 'made' (put up) it must be functioning as a roof of an *ohel*:

> דבעינן **בשעה שהוא עושה הסכך** יהיה נעשה לשם צל דהיינו אוהל וכל שאין מחיצות אלא 
>                      גג לחוד אין קרוי אהל ואם יעשה אח"כ המחיצות הוי ולא מן העשוי

It would therefore seem that in your case there is certainly no problem - when the schach was put up it functioned as a roof and continued to do so until all the walls were replaced.